# Is it ever possible to delete a URL path : Django

Tags: django, django-urls

I had in my urls.py file, ***url*** patterns for certain data processing requirements and later I realized that from among a bunch of them, one was not intended as its requirement had ceased.

However, when I am trying to delete the particular line (the second pattern in the excerpt of the urls.py reproduced here), I am getting the following error at page load ('**holding_list**'):

> NoReverseMatch at /supp/holding_comp/
>
> Reverse for 'holding_change' not found. 'holding_change' is
>   not a valid view function or pattern name.

I have checked all the references (I think) wherever the path might have been referred to (including the related template).

**urls.py**

```
    path('supp/holding_comp/', views.HoldingListView.as_view(), name='holding_list'),
...
...
    path('supp/holding_comp/edit/<int:pk>/', views.HoldingUpdateView.as_view(), name='holding_change'),
```

How do I delete the **second** url pattern (the one for "edit" view)?

I tried to look for a similar query but failed to (may be for want of a suitable search string). Any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: there are still things referring to the path, and you should find a way to remove these.

---

This error means that a template, in this case the template rendered by the `'holding_list'` view, contains a `{% url ... %}` template tag that refers to that `path(..)`.

You thus should search in the template for `{% url 'holding_change' ... %}` patterns, and decide what to do with links that refer to that path.

Note that this might not be sufficient: in order to be safe, you should search *all* templates and all Python files for `{% url ... %}` template tags, `redirect(..)`s, `reverse(..)`s, etc. You probably best search for `holding_change`, and thus look what might still refer to that URL.